# Sorteio de posiçoes de uma matriz

Tags: java, matriz, random

Preciso criar uma funçao para sortear dentro de uma matriz cheia de 0 com tamanho n x n, quatro posições para modificar o valor somente dessas posições sorteadas.

Comment: O que já tem desta função pronta? Podemos ajudar a montar sua função com base no que já fez

Answer (score 0):

Usa a class [java.util.Random](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) e depois algo deste género:

```
void fillRandomPositions(int[][] arr, int n, int positions) {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for(int i=0; i<positions; i++) 
        arr[rnd.nextInt(n)][rnd.nextInt(n)] = 1; // Inserir os valores aqui
}
```